# Azure ADD hide default URL and display desired URL with C#

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've connected to Azure active directory for initial log in authentication. It redirects to Microsoft's default URL for sign in page.

I would like to know if there is a way to hide this default URL and display my company's URL.

For example if my project's URL is something like `sample.cotoso.net`, then I would like to have the login page URL like `login.contoso.net` instead of `"https://login.microsoftonline.com/ed2df275-320a-4e02-98f1-8c58943da891/oauth2/authorize?client_id=bb685001-fe91-4164-b164-9c594caeb5ca&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44322%2F&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3DK6wVP9nPiji4ITCfDDVJi4oTgpsqsrCQU3fKL65EXmZYFfA_Ec4x0dFtKCiQ2c8nCA0W94l1YlgdiGZf-XQXDX1gBdKjcov49VHwrZuQ-aK51RQFevCZIU99dGgzKBWbPzJeNJbUzON5OP4OO7Lh4dUdvScjt5AINIUvh_DJHi8&nonce=636729522221121817.Mjc1YWUyN2ItN2ViNi00NWE3LWI2Y2QtYzBiNTM5OGUzOWI0ZmY4MGE5YTAtNTcwMS00ODNhLTkzOWUtMDYxN2U3NzIyMGUz&x-client-SKU=ID_NET451&x-client-ver=5.2.4.0"`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's not possible, though the product team hopes to make this available in the near future. This page details everything that can be customized, and unfortunately the login URL is not mentioned: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn532270.aspx

There's already a feature request for this in UserVoice for Azure B2C but you can create a second one for regular Azure AD: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334317-customer-owned-domains

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: No problem! Sorry it is not available.